# Understanding the concept of "arguments" and "parameters"

Tags: c, parameters, definition, declarations

In the third last paragraph at page number 26 of the **[ebook](https://archive.org/stream/pdfy-Ry7HcW4yeAIEgsSM/The_C_Programming_Language#page/n25/mode/2up)** "*The C Programming Language*" the author(s) say,

> "We will generally use *parameter* for a variable named in the parenthesized list in a function. The terms *formal argument* and *actual argument* are sometimes used for the same distinction."

And in the hard copy of the book that I am having, on the second last paragraph of page number 25 the author(s) say,

> "We will generally use *parameter* for a variable named in the parenthesized list in a function definition, and *argument* for the value used in a call of the function. The terms *formal argument* and *actual argument* are sometimes used for the same distinction."

If I understand it correctly, it means whatever the value(or variable) is used in the call of a function, that is called *argument*. And whatever is written in the paranthesis of the definition of a function, that is called *parameter*. E.g. in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int func(int j)
{  
    return j;  
}

main()  
{  
    int k=5;  
    printf("The argument = %d", func(k));  
}
```

the *parameters* are declared by the line `int func(int j)`. The argument given, through which `main()` and `func(int j)` communicate is `k`.

Now, on the page number 30 of the book(both, the ebook and the hard copy) the authors state,

> "`main` and `getline` communicate through a pair of arguments and a returned value. In
>   `getline`, the arguments are declared by the line
>
> `int getline(char s[], int lim);"`

As I understand, `char s[]` and `int lim` are *parameters*, because they are written in the definition of the function `getline`, not in the call of that function, so my question is,

**Why have the authors used the word argument in the second paragraph of page number 30?**

Comment: _"In  getline, the [formal] arguments are declared by the line"_

Comment: @CodeCaster _`main` and `getline` communicate through a pair of **arguments** and a returned value_ They are not using the word _formal argument_. They are using the word _argument_.

Comment: And they are using the word "generally" in "We will generally use parameter".

Comment: "generally" means in most of the cases.

Comment: So it took them four pages to make a typo/mistake/let out a word on purpose. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: @user31782: most != all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between arguments and parameters?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/168581/is-there-a-difference-between-arguments-and-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

English (and I presume other languages as well) has a lot of words which can be used in a generic sense, but are no longer correct in a context which requires more distinction.  For example, you can use the word "goose" to refer to a goose of any gender or age when speaking in the more common generic sense, but if a distinction must be made, a male goose is properly called a gander, and a baby goose is properly called a gosling.

"Argument" and "parameter" are two such words.  You can use "argument" in a more loose context to refer to either an argument or a parameter, but in certain circumstances it's helpful to be able to distinguish between them precisely.  Those circumstances are rare enough that many programmers don't learn the distinction for years, if ever.

Don't ask me why English is that way.  It wasn't designed for ease of parsing.

Comment: What are the meanings of _Argument_ and _Parameter_ in English and how are they similar?

Answer (score 1):

The term "argument" is often used rather loosely to refer to either *actual arguments* or *formal arguments* without giving the *actual* or *formal* adjective. Most often, the context makes it clear if *actual arguments* or *formal arguments*/*parameters* is meant.

In this case, it should be clear that the authors meant *formal arguments* or *parameters*. As to why they didn't use *parameters* is pure speculation. It can be a simple oversight or a deliberate choice because it made the text flow better.

Comment: Could you explain, what do you mean by _it made the text flow better._

Comment: @user31782: I mean that the word 'argument' just sounded better to them when writing this part than the word 'parameter'.

Comment: "Klingon function calls do not have 'parameters' - they have 'arguments' - and they ALWAYS WIN THEM." (#7 of [Top 12 things likely to be overheard if you had a Klingon Programmer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/129751/31260):)

Comment: If we can use _argument_ for _parameter_ whenever we want, then why was the concept of _parameter vs. argument_ developed?

Comment: @user31782: Because people got tired of mixing up actual arguments with formal arguments and they needed a different term for one of them perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's recap:

- "parameter = the variable's name"
- "argument = the expression we pass to the function"

Note too that "argument" isn't the variable's name. Therefore, it is *everything* else. Figuratively speaking, you can think of "argument" as a pipe/line. A line that connects the text in the source code holding the "actual argument" with the text in the source code naming the "formal argument".

This pipe has a type. It represent a C *cast*. A cast is defined by the *source* type and the *destination* type.

When they tell you that "the arguments are declared by the line int `getline(char s[], int lim)`" they tell you that here's the definition of the pipe (which is "argument"): its target type is "char []" (and source type can be anything).

Comment: Could you explain you answer in detail with examples. I don't understand this line "_A line that connects the text in the source code holding the "actual argument" with the text in the source code naming the "formal argument"._" I also do not know what a _cast_ is.

Comment: @user31782:  If you don't know what a cast is, you need to read the rest of the book, or at least the next 20 pages.

Comment: @Blrfl Ok        ${}{}{}{}{}{}$